# Multiple if conditions ,how to optimize it

Tags: java

i am working on a large application which has differnt conditions(ifs) and different  methods associated with it.Please suggest a way to optimize below mentioned code(reduce as much of nested ifs as possible).I would like the code to able incorporate any other specific condition with ease.(I use property files to fetch conditions)
.

```
 public getParameter(String parameter)
    {
      if(parameter=specific condition1
        ||parameter=specific condition2)
      {
      do this
      }
      if(parameter=specific condition3)
      {
       do something else
      }
      if(parameter=specific condition4)
      {
       do something else
      }
      if(parameter=general condition)
      {
       do something else
      }
      else  {
       do something else
      }
```

Comment: Start by introducing some `else`s if the conditions are mutually exclusive. No sense in doing all the `if` checks if only one will ever be true.

Comment: And I'm not sure comparing strings with `==` is a good idea, unless this is not how your real code looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a property file with

```
do1=val1,val2,val3
do2=val5,val6,val7
```

(it seems you have a fixed set of actions)

You may load it with

```
    HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> rules = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
    for(String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(properties.getProperty(key).split(",")));
        rules.put(key, set);
    }
```

Now you have a map linking action names ("do1", etc.) to sets of possible values ("val1", etc.).

You may execute the rules with

```
    if (rules.get("do1").contains(parameter)) do1();
    if (rules.get("do2").contains(parameter)) do2();
```

(I let you add the necessary checks to avoid null pointer exceptions for example)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a switch case.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: my cases are not mutually exclusive ,there are specific as well as general conditions